# How can I produce an OSD in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to create an on-screen display, i.e. text or simple graphics that appear on top of everything else being displayed. I know in Linux this is achieved with xosd, but how do you do it in Windows? (Assume XP and up if it makes it easier, and I would also be interested in knowing if the method is different in Vista/7)

Comment: Is it enough to just display a non-activated always-on-top window, or do you want to draw text and simple graphics directly on the screen surface?

Comment: Directly I guess - the user shouldn't be able to interact with it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NativeWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) to do this as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/OSDwindow.aspx).

> The article explains how to create an
>   OSD window with
>   animation/semi-transparent effects, in
>   C#, using the NativeWindow class.

Comment: I don't think ZoFreX was looking for C# code, but that article does use all the right Win32 APIs so duplicating the effect in native code should not be hard.

Comment: Yeah, the code is less important than explaining what properties the window needs, and why. That article contained exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style to make the window transparent, and `SetWindowPos(..., HWND_TOPMOST, ...)` to make it float above other windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [**SetForeGroundWindow**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: A OSD is usually not a active window, besides, you can't just call SetForeGroundWindow since only the foreground process is allowed to do that.